# How group dataset in a boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been trying to figure out how to group 9 datasets into 3 different groups (1, 2, and 3).
I have 3 different data frames that look like this:

```
ID1 ID2 dN  dS  Omega   Label_ID1   Label_ID2   Group
QJY77946     NP_073551   0.0293      0.0757      0.3872      229E-CoV    229E-CoV    Intra
QJY77954     NP_073551   0.0273      0.0745      0.3668      229E-CoV    229E-CoV    Intra
...
```

So, the only columns that I´m interested in are three: dN, dS, and Omega.
My main goal is to take these three columns from my data frames and plots in a boxplot using Rstudio.
To do that, first I take the 3 columns of each data frame with these lines:

```
dN_1 <- df_1$dN
dS_1 <- df_1$dS
Omega_1 <- df_1$Omega
```

Then, to generate the plot I use this line (option 1):

```
boxplot(dN_S, dS_S, Omega_S, dN_M, dS_M, Omega_M, dN_E, dS_E, Omega_E,
        main = "Test",
        xlab = "Frames",
        ylab = "Distribution",
        col = "red")
```

[image]

My goal is to group these 9 boxes into 3 separate groups:
[image]

I know that using ggplot2 could be easier, so my option 2 is to use these lines (option 2):

```
df_1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(y=dN_S)) +
  geom_boxplot(
    color = "blue", 
    fill = "blue",
    alpha = 0.2,
    notch = T,
    notchwidth = 0.8)
```

However, you can see that I couldn´t find a way to plot all groups in the same plot.
So how can I group my data in the boxplot using option 1 or option 2? Maybe the second option is less development but perhaps someone could help with that too.

Comment: Could you provide more data? I have an idea using `ggplot` but need more data from all three datasets to do it

Comment: combine the three data sets including a grouping variable based on the data and then facet by that variable

Comment: @akash87 here a link: https://github.com/MauriAndresMU1313/Example_Merge_Dataframes/blob/main/Main_dataframe (the data is so big)

Comment: Maybe your idea could work, however, I think that with facet you divide the box plot into different panels or not? @Peter

Comment: Okay how did you get `dn_S, dn_M,` and `dn_E`?

Comment: Sorry about that. dN_S == dN (group 1), dN_M == dN (group 2), is a simple form to see that. @akash87

Comment: Have a look at the suggested answer

Comment: @Peter nailed what I was thinking

Comment: Great! Anyway, thank both of you for your comment and give ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

df_s <- data.frame(dN = runif(20), 
                 dS = runif(20),
                 Omega = runif(20))

df_m <- data.frame(dN = runif(20), 
                   dS = runif(20),
                   Omega = runif(20))

df_e <- data.frame(dN = runif(20), 
                   dS = runif(20),
                   Omega = runif(20))

df <- 
  list(df_s, df_m, df_e) %>% 
  set_names(c("S", "M", "E")) %>% 
  map_dfr(bind_rows, .id = "df") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-df)

ggplot(df)+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = name, y = value))+
  facet_wrap(~df, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Great, thank @Peter that is how I thought my final boxplot!

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is by providing `ggplot()` another aesthetic, like `fill`. Here's a small reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(category = rep(letters[1:4], 5),
             time = c(rep("before", 10), rep("after", 10)),
             num = rnorm(20))

df %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=category, y=num, fill = time))
```

[image]

Let me know if you're looking for something else.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have one question, to do that I suppose that I must modify my data frame? I don´t understand if my data is ready to do like your example.

Comment: If you provide some data by posting the output of `dput()` I can take a look. But I'm assuming you want to group them based on a feature that is captured in the data. Is this the case? And if so, is the grouping variable in a distinct column?

Comment: https://github.com/MauriAndresMU1313/Example_Merge_Dataframes/blob/main/Main_dataframe Here is a link with the complete data. I want to group based only on the name, for example: group 1: dN, dS and Omega (1), group 2: dN... (2)... These columns had only numbers.

Comment: Looks like Peter might have you covered in his answer :)